# Parsing a string into a timestamp is cutting off the year part of the string

Tags: go, timestamp

I have a string that has a timestamp in the format

"2021-02-04 23:45:00" but when I try and parse this with time.parse it seemingly cuts off the year part.

The code is

```
case "period_end":
                fmt.Println(record[i])
                ts, err := time.Parse("2021-02-04 23:45:00", record[i])
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Time conversion failed: %v", err)
                    return
                }
reading.Interval = t
```

where record[i] at this point is a string with

2021-02-04 00:15:00

and reading.Interval is time.Time

The error returned in the Printf is

```
Time conversion failed: parsing time "2021-02-04 00:15:00" as "2021-02-04 23:45:00": cannot parse "-02-04 00:15:00" as "1"
```

which I can't find in any search I've done. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the first parameter in time.Parse:

from

```
"2021-02-04 23:45:00"
```

to

```
"2006-01-02 15:04:00"
```

Golang uses a specific date for formatting, no idea why https://golang.org/src/time/format.go

Comment: Well I'll be... missed that one... thanks.. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Definitely have made that mistake myself! Glad it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Go uses this default time for setting up the layout:

```golang
"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
```

More [info](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) for this layout:

> The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
>
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference time can be thought of as
>
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700

So to solve your problem:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    recordTime := "2021-02-04 23:45:00"
    ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", recordTime)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(ts)
}
```

This code can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/2Vvb-abRvb_3).